# How can I expose .Net web service service running under https: to javascript?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-4.0

I'm exposing a web service to my client side javascript using .Net's Scriptmanager as follows:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server">
    <services>
        <asp:servicereference Path="RmUiControlDataSVC.svc" />
    </services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In my javascript I can call it like this:

```
var service = new RmUiControlDataSVC();
```

When I run this from my local server, it works fine and I can run the methods within. It also runs when I deploy remotely and connect to my site using `http:`.(working on my site http://myserver/msftqa/RmMain.aspx) However, the problem comes in when I attempt to connect to the same application using `https:`(https://mysite.com/msftqa/RmMain.aspx). Now when I attempt to access the methods of the service, I get a

> 503 Service Unavailable

Inspecting through Firebug reveals that my Svc is attempting to bind using `http:` instead of `https:` and is this not able to find the service. Here is the relevent section of the web.config

```
  <service name="Company.App.RM.RmUiControlDataSVC">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Company.App.RM.RmUiControlDataAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Company.App.RM.RmUiControlDataSVC" />
  </service>
```

Is there a way that I can tell the service to use `https:` when connected through https but still have it work when I connect using `http:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing WCFs over http and https means that you need two endpoints. You can configure declaratively or programmatically:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-programmatically-configure-ssl.html